# Efficiency Analysis of the Euclidean GCD algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, euclidean-algorithm

The question is, if the Euclidean algorithm is called with values $p$, and $q$ such that $p < q$. Then runtime of the Euclidean algorithm is upper bounded by $O(\log_{3/2}(p+q))$. How can this be proved?

It means that the variables, will decrease by factor of $3/2$ on every step. So let's say the Euclidean algorithm has variables $m$ and $n$.

**In step 1**: m = p, n = q

**Step 2**: m = p mod q and n = p

and so on

So if we prove that, (m+n in step 1)/(m+n in step 2) >= 3/2 then we can solve the question.

I tried something like:

**step 1**: m = p, n = q

**step 2**: m = p', n= q'

q' = p and

p' = p mod q which is definitely <= p

this means q'+ p' <= 2p

But this is not taking me anywhere. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: "Euclidean's" is not good English. Use either "Euclid's" (belonging to Euclid) or Euclidean (an adjective; in the style of Euclid, or named after Euclid). Since Euclid himself did not use a "modulo" operation (just subtractions) I would say "Euclidean" is best here. I'll change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we apply one step of the algorithm to the pair $(p, q)$ with $p\leq q$, and we get the pair $(q', p)$ as a result, with $q'<p$. We now split into cases:

- If $p \geq \frac q2$, then $$\begin{align}q'+p&{}\leq(q-p)+p\\
  &=q\\
  &=\frac23\left(q+\frac12q\right)\\
  &\leq \frac23(q+p)\end{align}$$
- If $p\leq \frac q2$, then $$\begin{align}q'+p\leq{}& 2p\\={} &\frac23\cdot3p\\={}&\frac23(2p+p)\\\leq{}&\frac23(q+p)\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that I am pretty certain we can do better if we analyze two steps of the algorithm. I suspect we will find that after two steps we can bound the change of the sum to a factor closer to $2.5$ rather than just $(3/2)^2=2.25$. The best possible long-term bound (for very many steps) is $\phi^n$, where $n$ is the number of steps, and $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: Preliminary brute-force testing leads me to believe that we do indeed have $2.5$ as the optimal bound for two steps, and the relevant case-split seems to be at $p = \frac 23q$. I don't think I will bother doing the actual work to prove it, though. I'm fine with leaving it as a guess.